# GPS location fetching never stops on ICS

Tags: android, gps, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, locationmanager

I try to make a two step location detection with my `LocationListener`. It works as expected on each android version as expected. Only on ICS I can't stop the GPS location detection.

```
// inner class inside my PoiActivity
private class CustomLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    String currentProvider = LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER;

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {
            if (currentProvider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
                System.out.println(this);
                mLastKnownLocation = location;
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                Log.i("CustomLocationListener", "Got a rough location, removing the network listener ");
                Toast.makeText(PoiActivity.this, "Network found and removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mLocationManager
                        .requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, Constants.LOCATION_MAX_ACCURACY, this);
                currentProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
            } else if (location.getAccuracy() < Constants.LOCATION_MAX_ACCURACY
                       && currentProvider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
                System.out.println(this);
                mLastKnownLocation = location;
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
                mLocationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                Log.i("CustomLocationListener", "Got a rough location, removing the gps listener ");
                Toast.makeText(PoiActivity.this, "GPS found and removed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

Based on the Toast and the LogCat information, the listener are removed and on every version except ICS I see the GPS icon disappearing. On ICS the icon reappear after a couple of seconds but I never got the Toasts more than once, so my listener is successfully removed.

Killing the app with a task manager or via the application information doesn't stop the GPS icon to appear again and again.

I guess it is a specific ICS issue, but I can't find a bug report for that or similar problem descriptions.

Does someone have a workaround? Because I don't want the user to get the feeling that I pull several times and consume battery without any benefit...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've seen several sources (none of them definitive) which hint that the icon status may not reflect the state of the GPS chip. In order to find out if the GPS is actually running you could write a test app which only uses a PASSIVE_PROVIDER and fires a Toast or sends the location to a text box on location changed if the source is the GPS.

Although my phone's icon seems to behave itself, I've written a test 'dirty app' which only removes location updates in onDestroy not in onPause. So when I start this app and press 'home' it goes to background but leaves the GPS on. If I then run the passive provider app this picks up location updates.

You could do something similar in order to put your mind at rest, (or otherwise).